# iphone SDK - How to Connect 2 controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

hello
I have a problem with 2 controllers.
the first controller running an tableview populated by a list of names and when I select a name on the first controller should pass the name chosen in the second controller.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare properties in the second view controller for the things you want to pass to it. Then, it `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` set those properties from the first view controller.